# Wordpress Custom Logo sizing

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-theme

I am trying to generate a logo in my Wordpress custom theme.  I can get it to show up but I cannot get it to resize.  In addition to what I have now, I have also tried the "add_image_size()" function but it did not work either.  The code I currently have is:

```
    <?php
    function mytheme_setup() {

    add_theme_support( 'custom-logo', array(
       'height'      => 100,
       'width'       => 77,
       'flex-width' => true,
    ) );
    }

    add_action('after_setup_theme', 'mytheme_setup');
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to regenerate the thumbnails on your website after adding new thumbnail sizes, Wordpress won't automatically do this for you.

Install and run this plugin: [Regenerate Thumbnails](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/)